# Print preview xulrunner

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

So I'm having this problem with opening print preview in xulrunner.
I open print preview but i can't get the navigation toolbar.
This is the code from PrintUtils.js where the toolbar is created:

```
var XUL_NS = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
        printPreviewTB = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "toolbar");
        printPreviewTB.setAttribute("PrintPreview", true);
        printPreviewTB.id = "print-preview-toolbar";
        printPreviewTB.className = "toolbar-primary";
```

And later it does this:

```
var navToolbox = this._callback.getNavToolb
    navToolbox.parentNode.insertBefore(printPreviewTB, browser);
```

I'm providing the navToolbox, that's the place where the toolbar is inserted but it doesn't show. As I said, print preview opens perfectly, pages formatted and everything but without toolbar.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found soulution, if anyone is interested.

So when enternig printPreview you have to pass an object with 5 functions:
`getSourceBrowser`, `getPrintPreviewBrowser`, `getNavToolbox`, `onEnter` and `onExit`.

With `getNavToolbox` you pass the reference to toolbar (placeholder) where you want to place standard navigation toolbar (with print button, zoom, and others).

I have done all that but you have to bind to that toolbar, like this :

```
toolbar.style.MozBinding = url('chrome://global/content/printPreviewBindings.xml#printpreviewtoolbar')";
```

I'm doing that in the onEnter function.

But i also had problem with the `enterPrintPreview` function from `PrintUtils.js`.
In this part of code:

```
var printPreviewTB = document.getElementById("print-preview-toolbar");
        if (printPreviewTB) {            
          printPreviewTB.updateToolbar();
          tmptoolbar.updateToolbar();
          var browser = this._callback.getPrintPreviewBrowser();
          browser.collapsed = false;
          browser.contentWindow.focus();
          return;
        }
```

`printPreviewTB.updateToolbar();` throws error.

I fixed this by getting the reference to the toolbar that i passed in `getNavToolbox` function and then calling `updateToolbar` on him, like this:

```
var printPreviewTB = document.getElementById("print-preview-toolbar");
        if (printPreviewTB) {
          var tmptoolbar = this._callback.getNavToolbox();            
          tmptoolbar.updateToolbar();
          var browser = this._callback.getPrintPreviewBrowser();
          browser.collapsed = false;
          browser.contentWindow.focus();
          return;
        }
```

And now everything works fine.